# Vuejs search in array of object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

i have an API Laravel response such this:

```
{
id:1, 
name: "Text",
category: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Text 2",
          },
tags:[
       {
         id: 1,
         name: "Tag1",
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         name: "Tag2",
       },
     ],
},
```

For my front-end (with vuejs) i've created a simple computed function to filter the category, based on the user's selection of checkboxes.

```
checkedCategory: []
.
.
let posts = this.posts;
if (typeof this.checkedCategory !== 'undefined' && this.checkedCategory.length > 0) {
          posts = posts.filter((post) => {
                     return this.checkedCategory.indexOf(post.category.name) > -1;})}
```

Everything works.Posts are filtered by the categories chosen by the user.

**But, posts can also have several tags.**
Is an array of objects, so i reformulated the block with an *.includes* (instead of .filter), but it returns an empty result.

```
checkedTags: []
.
.
let posts = this.posts;
if (typeof this.checkedTags !== 'undefined' && this.checkedTags.length > 0) {
          posts = posts.includes((post) => {
                     return this.checkedTag.indexOf(post['tags']) > -1;})}
```

Comment: includes returns true/false

Comment: And includes does not provide a parameter if you pass a function to it. `post` in inside `.includes()` is undefined.

Comment: Not sure why you changed from `filter` to `includes` (although as mentioned not used correctly). Instead you could filter on tags by `posts.tags.filter(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```js
let posts = this.posts;
if (typeof this.checkedTags !== 'undefined' && this.checkedTags.length > 0) {
  posts = posts.filter(post => {
    return post.tags.some(tag => checkedTags.includes(tag.name))
  })
}
```

Basically it will just filter all the posts where at least one tag is in the `checkedTags` array. Depending on your needs you can also check if all the `tags` of the post are there with `post.tags.every()`